# Clustered standard errors different in plm vs lfe

Tags: r, plm, lfe

When I run a cluster standard error panel specification with `plm` and `lfe` I get results that differ at the second significant figure. Does anyone know why they differ in their calculation of the SE's?

```
set.seed(572015)
library(lfe)
library(plm)
library(lmtest)
# clustering example
x <- c(sapply(sample(1:20), rep, times = 1000)) + rnorm(20*1000, sd = 1)
y <- 5 + 10*x + rnorm(20*1000, sd = 10) + c(sapply(rnorm(20, sd = 10), rep, times = 1000))
facX <- factor(sapply(1:20, rep, times = 1000))
mydata <- data.frame(y=y,x=x,facX=facX, state=rep(1:1000, 20))
model <- plm(y ~ x, data = mydata, index = c("facX", "state"), effect = "individual", model = "within")
plmTest <- coeftest(model,vcov=vcovHC(model,type = "HC1", cluster="group"))
lfeTest <- summary(felm(y ~ x | facX | 0 | facX))
data.frame(lfeClusterSE=lfeTest$coefficients[2],
       plmClusterSE=plmTest[2])

lfeClusterSE plmClusterSE
1   0.06746538   0.06572588
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is in the degrees-of-freedom adjustment. This is the usual first guess when looking for differences in supposedly similar standard errors (see e.g., [Different Robust Standard Errors of Logit Regression in Stata and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/)). Here, the problem can be illustrated when comparing the results from (1) `plm`+`vcovHC`, (2) `felm`, (3) `lm`+`cluster.vcov` (from package `multiwayvcov`).

First, I refit all models:

```
m1 <- plm(y ~ x, data = mydata, index = c("facX", "state"),
  effect = "individual", model = "within")
m2 <- felm(y ~ x | facX | 0 | facX, data = mydata)
m3 <- lm(y ~ facX + x, data = mydata)
```

All lead to the same coefficient estimates. For `m3` the fixed effects are explicitly reported while they are not for `m1` and `m2`. Hence, for `m3` only the last coefficient is extracted with `tail(..., 1)`.

```
all.equal(coef(m1), coef(m2))
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(coef(m1), tail(coef(m3), 1))
## [1] TRUE
```

The non-robust standard errors also agree.

```
se <- function(object) tail(sqrt(diag(object)), 1)
se(vcov(m1))
##          x 
## 0.07002696 
se(vcov(m2))
##          x 
## 0.07002696 
se(vcov(m3))
##          x 
## 0.07002696
```

And when comparing the clustered standard errors we can now show that `felm` uses the degrees-of-freedom correction while `plm` does not:

```
se(vcovHC(m1))
##          x 
## 0.06572423 
m2$cse
##          x 
## 0.06746538 
se(cluster.vcov(m3, mydata$facX))
##          x 
## 0.06746538 
se(cluster.vcov(m3, mydata$facX, df_correction = FALSE))
##          x 
## 0.06572423
```

Comment: Examining `multiwayvcov::cluster.vcov` it is easy to see the algebra used to obtain the Stata small-sample degrees-of-freedom correction, namely: `(df$M/(df$M - 1)) * ((df$N - 1)/(df$N - df$K))`. But what would be the equivalent df correction as used is `sandwich(..., adjust=TRUE)`? In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367974/) you explain that the difference between the two is that for Stata the division is by `1/(n - 1)`, and for `sandwich` it is by `1/(n - k)`. Yet I'm unsure how this translates into appropriate algebra... Do I replace `(df$N - 1)` by `(df$N - df$K)` above?

Comment: I think so but haven't checked the code in detail. Also note that currently `sandwich` itself does not offer clustered standard errors at the moment. All theoretical details behind the `sandwich` package are also documented in the two vignettes.

Comment: Update: Clustered covariances are now also available in `sandwich`. The `cluster.vcov()` function from `multiwayvcov` has been rewritten and extended and has been incorporated as `vcovCL()` into `sandwich`. See https://CRAN.R-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich-CL.pdf